# Detect Which URL's An HTML Email Is Accessing?

Tags: logging, media-queries, html-email, email-client

Is there a way of detecting what sites and URL's an HTML email is accessing when loaded in an email client (e.g. on iPhone Mail App or Airmail on OS X)?

I am looking for a way to log these.

Comment: it's html. use a dom parser and look for `src=`, `href=`, etc...

Comment: I have.  But what I am asking is if there is a way to log the network traffic (sites and URL's accessed) that the email uses when it calls outwards to get the information it needs when displaying in the email client.

Comment: unless a user's explicitly allowed it, mail clients don't fetch external resources automatically. automatic fetching = hostile crap, privacy invasions, blah blah blah

Comment: That's not the case in my experience.  For example, iOS mail app fetches images, CSS, etc. into HTML emails from URL's in the email when the email is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is analytics, no?

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008015?hl=en&ref_topic=3544906

You can set up a Google Analytics for your site, and then UTM tracking codes for your links, and as long as the links are going to a site you have tracking set up on, you will be able to see who clicked on what and on what device.

Comment: For more in depth email-specific tracking, I'd recommend using Litmus' tracking since it's better at finding out which Email clients your audience is using.

Comment: I don't create these emails - I'm looking to monitor/log from the client side. I want to know what outbound calls these HTML emails are making.